# Subrepresentations of $\mathbb{I} \oplus \xi$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, representation-theory

$G=C_2=\{e,h \}$.

$\mathbb{I}$ is the trivial representation and $\xi$ is the sign representation.

Let us consider $\mathbb{I} \oplus \xi$ where $e \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 &  0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $h \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} -1 &  0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Now apparently there are 4 subrepresentations $\{0\}, \mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}e_1,\mathbb{R}e_2$.

Now I wanted to show why this is true, so I started by calculating eigenvectors and eigenvalues (through Wolfram alpha) and got

$\begin{pmatrix} 1 &  0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ and eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

and

$\begin{pmatrix} -1 &  0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ has eigenvalues $\lambda=\pm 1$ and eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

So as far as I can see for $\lambda=1$ we have the joint eigenvector $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. This would imply the $\mathbb{R}e_2$ case so how are we getting the others?

Comment: In looking for subrepresentations, you are looking for invariant subspaces. These are subspaces fixed by all group elements. I think you have demonstrated that the one dimensional subspaces generated by $e_1$ and $e_2$ are both fixed by both of e and h.

Comment: Could you explain further how I have done this.

Comment: A one-dimensional subspace $\langle v\rangle$ is invariant iff $gv\in\langle v\rangle$ for all $g\in G$, which in this case just means that $hv$ is a scalar multiple of $v$ for your nontrivial element $h$. Can you justify what I just said? Can you verify that $he_1$ is a scalar multiple of $e_1$, and $he_2$ is a scalar multiple of $e_2$? Do you know why $\{0\}$ and $\Bbb R^2$ are representations without having to do any work?

Comment: @anon I can see why $\{0\}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are true now. Im going to have a think about your point before now

Comment: @anon Ok so I could do this by brute force but I thought I had to do it with eigenvectors. Could you please explain whats wrong with my method?

Comment: I assume your method is to find "joint eigenvectors" for every eigenvalue. Say $G$ acts on a space $V$. If for some value $\lambda$ and vector $v$ the equality $gv=\lambda v$ is true, then $\langle v\rangle$ will indeed be a one-dim subrep. However the converse is not true: in order for $\langle v\rangle$ to be a subrep, the vector $v$ must indeed be an eigenvector of every group element $g$, but *not necessarily with the same eigenvalue* for every group element. Go back to the definitions and make sure you understand them: in order for $\langle v\rangle$ to be a subrep,

Comment: for each $g$ we must have $g\langle v\rangle\subseteq\langle v\rangle$, equivalently for each $g$ there is some $\lambda$ for which $gv=\lambda v$ (do you see why this is equivalent?). That does not imply $\lambda$ is the same for each $g$! Thus the work you've done already proves $\langle e_1\rangle$ is a subrep. I am not sure I would call this brute force - we've unpackaged the definition of subrep into concrete, directly verifiable claims, and then we verify these claims.

Comment: @anon This constitutes a full answer not a comment